# Inter executor communication in Storm worker

Tags: worker, executor, apache-storm

Suppose I have a topology with one spout S feeding a bolt A. Suppose also I run this topology in a single worker.

**My questions**

- Does the send thread of the executor running S move tuples from S' outgoing queue to A' incoming queue directly or does it move them to the shared LMAX disruptor maintained by the worker?
- If the latter is the correct answer, which thread moves then tuples outputted by S to the incoming queue of A?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/